# Multiple (single) dates selector using jquery ui datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Pleease check here:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html

As you can see, this plugin; the datepicker lets you **choose** multiple (and isolated, I mean, its not a daterange) **dates**, as a toggle button

Is there any workaround to implement this with the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: Nope, it was designed to get a single date only and populate a field with it. The best solution to your problem is probably to generate multiple fields, each with its own calendar datepicker.

Comment: Might be what you're looking for: [http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @maddjak That looks awesome! lets dig into it!

Comment: @maddjak maybe you want to post it as an answer ;) and check my follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076221/jquery-multidatespicker-for-datepicker-restrict-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MultiDatesPicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) (an extension of the jQuery UI Datepicker) can do this.