# jQuery MultiDatesPicker for datepicker: Restrict range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I [decided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075348/multiple-single-dates-selector-using-jquery-ui-datepicker) to use this addon for the jQuery UI Datepicker,

Wich seems to work great, for example:

```
$(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    $('#test').multiDatesPicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        addDisabledDates: [today.setDate(1), today.setDate(3)]
    );
});
```

This allows user to select as many days as he wants except the 1st and the 3rd of current month,

but how could I restrict the user to select dates only greater than a desired date (start) and smaller than another desired date?

I don't see any method for that in their [documentation](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/#maxPicks-demo)

PD: As a workaround, it ocours to me to create an array with the dates before/after my desired interval, but how could I mark it all? (I mean, how many years should I contempl in this array??)

-EDIT-

Just to test, I am trying to disable the 15 days before and 15 days after from my desired range, like this:

```
$(function () {
        var start = new Date(2013, 11, 20)
        var end =  new Date(2013, 11, 24)

        console.log(start, end);

        var dissabledDates = [];
        if ( end < start ) {
            alert('Está mal');
        }

        for ( i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++ ){
            var currentDate = new Date();
            currentDate.setDate( start.getDate() - i );
            dissabledDates[ dissabledDates.length ] = currentDate;
        }
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++ ){
            var currentDate = new Date();
            currentDate.setDate( end.getDate() + i );
            dissabledDates[ dissabledDates.length ] = currentDate;

            console.log(currentDate);
        }


        var today = new Date();
        $('#test').multiDatesPicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            addDisabledDates: dissabledDates
        });
    });
```

And the restriction happens, but, look how the selector looks (note I only restricted 15 days before and after)

[image]

so question is: how can I only let user select between my start and end dates?

Comment: You looking for http://jsfiddle.net/kZBEt/370/ ?

Comment: [min and max dates](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: @BrettWeber is correct - You can use jQueryUI Datepicker calls with MultiDatePicker.

Comment: Tried and works, a bit silly the question if I knew that its actually extending the UI DatePicker, if you guys want to post it as an answer so we can close the deal..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize the base functionality from the jQuery UI datepicker as stated [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
```

***From the API documentation:***

> **Multiple types supported:**
>
> *Date*: A date object containing the minimum date.
>
> *Number*: A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
>
> *String*: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs;
>   valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and
>   "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven
>   days from today.

Comment: Actually, from my example; i just setted min and max dates to my start and end dates and it just suited, thanks!